# I support someone/something "to"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"I support John to be our president." - I'm not sure whether this sentence is semantically correct. What I'm trying to say is that I support John (I would like him to be the president), and not that I support him, so **I** can be the president. If it's not correct, how can I put it elegantly (short), without having to say something like "I support John in order so he can be our president." Please don't stick to this particular example (John, president), what I'm looking for is "support/oppose" + someone/something + "to be".

Comment: Not "I support John for (our) President"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I support John to be our president.* gives the intended meaning quite clearly, at least to my ears.

*I support John **so as** to be president **myself**.* gives the unwanted impression.

Some other options:

*I support John **in becoming** president.*

*I support John **(so) that he may** be president.*

*I support **John's becoming** president.*

*I support John **for (the office of) president**.*

Keep in mind that you can exchange *to be* for *to become* in many of these examples so as to clarify the specific meaning.

Comment: Thanks, are you sure the original sentence is correct? "I support this legislature to become a law" - I guess it's also OK?

Comment: *support to be* is not a common formation.  I hesitate to call it either correct or incorrect.  There is nothing strictly wrong with your example, but keep in mind that the occasional person may have difficulty in understanding it.

Comment: What formation would you choose for this second example (legislature -> become law) to make it clear that 1) I support it, 2) I do it because I would like it to become a law?

Comment: I hope that this legislature becomes law./I want this legislature to become law./This legislature should be law.  All of these *imply* support.  It depends on the exact type of support that you mean, however.  If you mean active support, in which one contributes to the cause, then you may need to express that separately.  If you mean passive support, in which one simply likes the cause, then nothing more needs be added.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is to say "I support John for President".

Comment: If you add in the our that you put in parenthesis above, it makes a comical change in meaning.  I support John for our President.  I keep John going on behalf of our President.

Comment: In this particular example. You haven't answered my question (whether the sentence is correct). How about "I support this legislature to become a law"? Is it correct?